# Why am I getting 'No non-OData HTTP route registered.'

Tags: odata

I am trying to implement Odata on a controller for the first time and am getting the error in the subject.  I have tried many different methods i have found here and on other sites but I am not having any luck.

I have the following controller declared.

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query;

namespace Site.API.Areas.Prices.Controllers
{
    public class PricesController : ODataController
    {
        IPricesManager pricesManager;

        public PricesController()
        {
            this.pricesManager = new PricesManager();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetPrice()
        {

            var result = this.PricesManager.RetrieveAll();

            return Ok(result.AsQueryable());
        }
    }
}
```

And the following in my WebApiConfig

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<PricesModel>("Prices").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Facility);

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

If I were to call any one of my normal API's I would use:

```
https://localhost/API/Site.API/Prices/Prices
```

For OData I am trying

```
https://localhost/API/Site.API/odata/Prices
```

And I get the subject error as a result.  What am I missing?